# xcode Use the same images and xibs for iphone and ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, image, ipad

I am at the start of a new game. My last game was for the iPhone, and it had to double up for iPad.

Now with the iPhone 5 screen being larger than 4, and iPad and iPad mini, I want to program the game to display the correct size images. Is it possible to design large graphic for iPad and use the same images for iPhone (just display the image smaller when using iPhone 4 etc) or is it best to use two lots of images, iPad version and iPhone version? The problem here would be the size of the app. The App would double the download and install size as the graphics would be quite large, and this isnt something I want to do.

Is it possible to use the same xib for ipad and iphone, and then I could just get the code to detect the screen size and display the game correctly based on that?

Also, I have started the project as Cocos2d with Box2d with the latest download of Cocos2d. It starts off with just the code, should I work from the storyboard instead?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You cannot use single xib file for both iPhone and iPad (programmatically you can but that would screw your app).

2) While doing development using Cocos2D, my experience suggests do not use any xib or storyboard file. Else you will end up in a mess.

3) As far as the question for image size for different iOS devices is concerned, I would suggest you to go with separate images (only typical ones) for different iOS devices. If you have some buttons and simple curve based UI go for CoreGraphics so that you do not need those images. Only use images that are typical ones and use CoreGraphics for rest of the images

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So say for example, if I wasnt to use a story board, I would also have HelloWorldLayer.mm as HelloWorldLayer~ipad.mm? or could I just use the same .mm file?

Comment: No you don't need two class files for that. All you need is to distinguish whether the device is iPhone or iPad. This you can do in a single file only. Use this code for that    ------   if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)